# IO performance with a FUSE mount

Tags: ubuntu, fuse

Is there any way to measure performance on a FUSE-based mount that is mounted via long-running executable (no device is used, nor `/etc/fstab` entry added)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about a FUSE mount from a benchmarking perspective - it's just a filesystem.

Use bonnie, fio, whatever you like.

Comment: I know how to get metrics on a device, but not a mountpoint. Thanks (if this works).

Comment: @DustinOprea the major difference taking stats on a filesystem/mountpoint (as opposed to a raw device) is you're going through the operating system's VFS layer -- this adds some overhead as opposed to beating on a raw device, but on an otherwise-idle system it's essentially a constant amount of overhead and won't skew your results too much.